# Ebay Api - Get top selling items of a seller, for any particular period

Tags: ebay-api

I want to display the top 10 best selling items of a seller within a particular period, but can't find any ebay api to serve the purpose. I have looked into almost all order/item related calls.

[GetOrders](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html) is a call which returns orders for a seller in specified date range but it won't be efficient to display 'top selling' items, as I have to load all orders first and then sort them to show top 10 selling items.

Is there any better way to do this?

**Note:** [Terapeak](http://terapeak.com) has a similar feature where you can search for eBay seller and it shows the sold items for that period. It doesn't even need the eBay authentication i.e. you can look for the sales history for ANY seller (but GetOrders call needs eBay authentication). So there must definitely be some better way than GetOrders to do this.

It will be fine even if api call needs eBay authentication to see that seller's data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible through any of the eBay APIs.

Terapeak on the other hand is an [authorized analytics provider of eBay market data](http://www.terapeak.com/company/). Therefore they have direct access to tons of data for marketing analysis.